# Which is the standard in JSON: Objects inside Objects, or Objects inside Array

Tags: javascript, json

I've a question, not in how to do something but rather in the "standard" or "accepted" way.

Which of this is the preferred one, and why?

```
var data = {
    employees:{
        "John Williams":{
            ...
        },
        "Susane Rodgers":{
            ...
        },
        "Clint Eastwood":{
            ...
        }
    }
};

var data = {
    employees:[
        {
            name:"John Williams",...
        },
        {
            name:"Susane Rodgers",...
        },
        {
            name:"Clint Eastwood",...
        }
    ]
};
```

Comment: Neither.  The 2nd, I think may be more commonly used, but there is no "standard".  Pick the one you like and use it.

Comment: Why would one be standard. They are different things. What is more standard a horse or a cow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically your data structure. The only thing that is "accepted" or preferred in data structures is simplicity. However many times it turns out that an API or old code has been written in a way that forces you to use a certain data structure. In your case, the first example suggests that there will not be employees with the same name, which is unacceptable since people with the same names exist and thus your application has a potential weakness. So the second example would be the better choice in that case.

Comment: I didn't think of the unique name issue you bring up.  That's a good point.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the other answer, something else to consider about your data structure is how you plan on using the data. Depending on what your insertion / retrieval / removal / etc needs are, you may decide that one data structure is easier for you to use. Because you're using objects or arrays, you'll have access to different methods for you to manipulate your data structure.